# Migration of moss 2007 to sharepoint 2010 custom solution

Tags: web-part, migration, custom

Hi have a visual studio custom webpart solution build in 2005. This solution does not have a .wsp file.when i open the solution in visual studio 2010 and build it - it succeeds but when i try to run to it - I get the error below.

```
Unable to start the project 
c:/project/Companyname/trunk/solution name/bin/xxx.dll
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest creating a new empty sharepoint project template in visual studio 2010, add the old code files and any other files, build the project and when you want to get the wsp - right click on solution explorer and click on package,

otherwise you may create the wsp manually using post build command